# How do you get the SimpleMenuButton to display the MenuItem text in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I am building an inventory management system for work and am having a lot of trouble getting the SplitMenuButton to display the MenuItem when I click on the item. I can not find much information on the 'SplitMenuButton' on the internet and have tried just MenuButton as well with no luck. For example, the default text is 'Department' and I would like it to display 'Aseptic' when that menu item is selected or 'Facilities' when that menu item is selected.

I have tried to create a new instance of SplitMenuButton and setText("Aseptic") when the #buildDataAseptic method is run, but this still didn't work.

My fxml code is:

```
<SplitMenuButton mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="217.0" text="Department" textAlignment="CENTER">
                <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="asepticMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buildDataAseptic" text="Aseptic" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="generalMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buildDataGeneral" text="General" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="facilitiesMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buildDataFacilities" text="Facilities" />
                </items>
              </SplitMenuButton>
```

any help is greatly appreacitead, thanks!

Comment: This sounds more like a [`ChoiceBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html) or [`ComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html). What behavior are you actually looking for from this control?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I would like it to display department, and then have a drop down to choose either aseptic, general, or facilities. I am changing the database of parts depending on this selection, but even though it changes the database it always shows Department. I want it to show Aseptic  for aseptic selection, General for general selection and same for facilities.

Comment: so the user can see what department they have selected.

Comment: So why not use a `ChoiceBox` or `ComboBox`?

Comment: I will try that, I am really new to this and still learning. So is it not possible to change the text on a split menu item?

Comment: Well of course it is, but why use that when the other controls seem to meet your needs better?

Comment: I will try to swap to a choicebox then I think, I did some more reading on it. I have it all working with the SplitMenuButton and it took a long time to get it working. Maybe I will try to work on some other parts of the program and come back to it when I am not burned out on trying to get it to work. I am learning a lot, but it is still very difficult. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, ComboBox is a much better choice for your use case.

Here is a self contained example. First the FXML:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import java.lang.String?>
<ComboBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/javafx/null">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Aseptic" />
            <String fx:value="General" />
            <String fx:value="Facilities" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ComboBox>
```

And the application with comments:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("test.fxml"));

        // Create an observable property for the selection
        SimpleStringProperty selected = new SimpleStringProperty();

        // Bind the property to the comboBox
        selected.bindBidirectional(comboBox.valueProperty());

        // Set initial value
        selected.set("Facilities");

        // React to changes
        selected.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            // newValue contains the new selection, update database
            System.out.println(newValue);
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(comboBox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

General advice: Don't hang on to the SplitMenuButton just because you've spent a lot of time on it. Think of this as a learning experience. If you don't learn to let go and refactor, you'll never create good software :)